# Boost thread - Out of scope possibility

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I was curious about the accuracy of the following code

```
for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
SomeClass* ptrinst = new SomeClass()
boost::thread t(  boost::bind (&SomeClass::SomeMethod,ptrinst));
......
}
```

What would happen to the running thread when t runs out of scope ?

Comment: The threads continue to run, but you have no means of waiting for them.

Comment: Why are threads local?

Answer (score 2):

Since the main thread does not call `t.join()`, the main thread will continue to run its loop, spawning additional threads and then continue onwards.  So the answer is, under your current coding, the child threads will not interact with your parent thread (at least not directly).

Also note that the `thread` class is a strange beast - the only thing that happens when you *fall out of scope* is, your main thread no longer has a handle to call `t.join()` on.  The fact that it *falls out of scope* of the parent thread has zero impact on the child thread.  Once you spawn your child thread by instantiating it, the child is, essentially, decoupled from the parent (well, the globals/dynamically allocated memory that were visible in the parent are also visible to the child, but you will need mutexes if you want to modify/mutate those globals).  As I mentioned later in the post, you need to gain a solid understanding of memory visibility and ownership within a threading context.  Just reading my comments here probably will not help you.

If you want the main thread to wait on the completion of the child threads, you need to store those threads in a `std::vector<boost::thread> v;` outside of your loop and then in a second loop, call `join` on all those instances.

Your current code looks a bit suspect as you are invoking an instance method through bind - that's fine, but I wouldn't normally expect that instance method to call `delete this;` which means it's up to the parent thread to clean up (the parent thread shouldn't clean up until the child threads are done).  However, there is no way for it to clean up at the right time without some kind of thread synchronization.  Hence, a memory leak or some kind of nasty race condition is almost assured (suppose you put a `delete ptrinst;` in the `...` portion of your main thread in an attempt to clean-up.  Without some kind of synchronization, you may delete the pointer before the child threads are done using it).

**Also, you may want to use `std::thread` and `std::bind` in place of the boost versions.**

One last note: I suspect you are still experimenting with the use of threads.  If this is true, it may be a good idea to read up and experiment a lot more with simpler examples until you try to fix this code.  Otherwise, you may be setting yourself for a world of hurt (debugging hell including race conditions, weird memory synchronization issues, etc...).

Try to build a more solid understanding of what happens with memory and threads: what memory is visible to what threads and what memory can and cannot be shared.